# how to declare a variable to stored proc

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am creating a stored  proc in MS SQL Server 2008.

Here in my SP, after an insert statement, an identity value for that row inserted will be

generated. I am using that in another insert Statement.

```
@SID int

insert into table1(SNAME) values('Sname')

set @SID=SCOPE_IDENTITY()

insert into table2(SID)values(@SID)
```

here, my doubt is , is it required to add @SID as a parmeter in C# code.

how to declare a variable that do not expect  any parameter ? since it is getting the value

from the SP itself..

Please help

Comment: I can see people posting same answer over and over for you :)

Comment: No, you don't need to declare the parameter in the C# code if you don't intend to use it in code. However your declaration of the @SID variable inside the stored proc is wrong `DECLARE @SID int`

Comment: You don't need to add the @SID as a parameter from your C# code as it seems you only need it inside your SP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the sql from

```
@SID int
```

to

```
DECLARE @SID int
```

Have a look at [DECLARE @local_variable (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188927.aspx)

> Variables are declared in the body of a batch or procedure with the
>   DECLARE statement and are assigned values by using either a SET or
>   SELECT statement. Cursor variables can be declared with this statement
>   and used with other cursor-related statements. After declaration, all
>   variables are initialized as NULL, unless a valu is provided as part
>   of the declaration.

Answer (score 2):

**[Declaring variable in SQL Server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188927%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)**

```
Declare @SID int    --Declaring variable in SQL Server
insert into table1(SNAME) values('Sname')
set @SID=SCOPE_IDENTITY()
insert into table2(SID)values(@SID)
```

Answer (score 2):

> my doubt is , is it required to add @SID in C# code

The question is `do you want this identity to be returned as an output parameter` to your class?

**If YES** then you will have to pass it as an output parameter. Like

```
@SID INT OUTPUT  -- as stored procedure parameter
```

**If NO** then all the variables that are required locally within the stored procedure will be declared locally. You only need to change

```
@SID int
```

To

```
DECLARE @SID int
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SPNAME
   @PARAM1 INT,
   @PARAM2 VARCHAR(10),
   .
   .
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @SID AS int

    insert into table1(SNAME) values('Sname')

    set @SID=SCOPE_IDENTITY()

    insert into table2(SID)values(@SID)

END
```

Answer (score 1):

For Oracle and DB2 declaring variable is,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Proc1()
 IS
  Declare 
  myName in varchar;
  STMT VARCHAR(4000);
 BEGIN 
  Select fname into myName from student where fname='x'; // is returning unique value
 END;
```